# SQL combine multiple rows based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table of separate travel transactions of Public Transport Users.
When travelers transit from line to line, they generate two distinct transactions.
Luckily the source data already contains a shared key (UniqueTravelID)

```
Date     | MediumID | UniqueTravelID | CiTime | CoTime | CiLocationID | CoLocationID  
1-1-2015 | 1001     | 99             | 08:10  | 08:15  | 5001         | 5050  
1-1-2015 | 1001     | 99             | 08:16  | 08:20  | 5001         | 5090
```

I would like to combine multiple distinct transactions based on the earliest Checkin and the latest Checkout time **on the same dates**.

```
Date     | MediumID | UniqueTravelID | CiTime | CoTime | CiLocationID | CoLocationID  
1-1-2015 | 1001     | 99             | 08:10  | 08:20  | 5001         | 5090
```

Comment: these represent legs of a journey.  likely min and max may be perfect for the times, but may not be accurate for the ci/co locationID fields -- right?  including window functions into the answer could help with this.  Also, is it possible that a single trip extend beyond a single date?  i.e. traveling before and after midnight.

Comment: Something like this is actually quite tricky in SQL. Can't you just handle this in the application?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but ...

1. Create a view grouped on date and UniqueTravelID that identifies unique journies for that date including the MIN CiTime and the MAX CoTime but exclude the Locations
2. Join the view with original table twice, one linking on Min CiTime and UniqueTravelID and the other on the Max CoTime and the UniqueTravelID and that should give you the answer.

Let me know if you want more information

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Date, 
  MediumID, 
  UniqueTravelID, 
  MIN(CiTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date ASC) CiTime,
  MAX(CoTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date ASC) CoTime, 
  FIRST_VALUE(CiLocationID) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date ASC) CiLocationID,
  LAST_VALUE(CoLocationID) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date ASC) CoLocationID
FROM
  table
```

In this [SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12bfe/2) you can find a working demo.
This only works on SQL Server 2012+

Hope this helps